# Page redirect for logout not working with delegated authentication (Azure API Management)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-api-management

I'm using Microsoft's Azure API Management, specifically the delegation feature, to handle login requests so my website can handle authentication for users visiting my developer portal on APIM.

I'm simply trying to handle a "SignOut" request whereby Azure API Management redirects to my `Delegation` page as follows:

```
    case "SignOut":
        //this doesn't actually log the user out; suggestions?
        return new RedirectToPageResult("Identity/Account/Logout");
```

The `logout` page only has a `POST` action:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
        if (returnUrl != null)
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

I would prefer to leave this page alone and simply 'use it' for my logout action from the delegated page handling events from APIM.

Any idea how to handle the logout using a redirect or other method? I know I'm missing something simple here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I don't think you can do that without additional client logic. HTTP redirect that server returns is 302 response with Location header with a new URL. The way browsers react to that is by issuing GET request on provided URL. Where as your signout logic required POST request. The only way to reuse your current POST endpoint for signout would be to return 200 response with client-side script that would invoke POST on required endpoint.

Personally I would rather prefer to do logout right there inside your delegation endpoint.

Comment: I ended up handling it in my login page's GET statement.